# insert a column with repeat alterna pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

Would like to add a column to a table that with the same alternate number or letter../

Here is the data frame:

```
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
 var1    var2 var3
 a         1   2
 b         3   4
 c         5   6
 d         7   8
 e         9   10
 f         11  12
 ')
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
> df2
var1 var2 var3 var4
a    1    2    11
b    3    4    12
c    5    6    11
d    7    8    12
e    9    10   11
f    11   12   12
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: If you know that you can assign a new variable like `df$var4 <- 1` and all the values are then repeated `1`, and instead of `1`, you want `c(11,12)`, then you should do......?

Comment: That does the trick!   Thanks thelatemail. I was over thinking the solution.                                                                                             df2$var4 <- c(11, 12)